# Forcing a div to be full page height without using 100vh

Tags: html, reactjs, css, css-grid

This is a simplified HTML & CSS code to what I currently have in project. Essentially since I'm using ReactJS & routes, I can't wrap everything inside another container with a css grid so I'm looking for solutions to get full page height on both the 'sidebar' & 'content' classes.

I do understand that I could use 100vh and substract from that the height of the header but in this case the header doesn't have a fixed height so I'm looking for alternatives.

```css
.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.2fr 1fr;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: lightpink;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div>
    One
  </div>
  <div>
   Two
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidebar">
    Menu
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/de5ut6np/39/

Comment: I suppose this is the final strucutre and everything is wrapper inside the body?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the body as the main container:

```css
html {
 height:100%;
}

body {
 margin:0;
 height:100%;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-rows: max-content 1fr;
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.2fr 1fr;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: lightpink;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div>
    One<br>
    more
  </div>
  <div>
   Two
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidebar">
    Menu
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is useful, however the reason I wasn't using another grid as a main container is because in my React setup, the "header" class is always there, however the "main" class is part of the routes and will change depending on the containers. Some might require the setup that I'm asking about here (with the sidebar), some might have just content in the center. So the grid doesn't fit me that well since it messes up the other containers that might not need it.

Comment: @leka74 ok got it, will think about another way

Comment: @leka74: if you need a different layout for a possible different container, you can always overwrite it in the style of the react component itself...

Answer (score -2):

I tested like this and it worked:

```css
html {
 height:100%;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 height:100%;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-rows: max-content 1fr;
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.2fr 1fr;
}

.sidebar {
  display: grid;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div>
    One
  </div>
  <div>
   Two
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidebar">
    Menu
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See my reply to Temani Afif. Issue with this approach is that the class 'main' might have different content depending on my react router and might not always need a sidebar. Some routes might have different structures that doesn't necessarily include a sidebar and content.